# What is the proper way to center a PyQT QGroupBox title?

Tags: python, user-interface, pyqt, qtstylesheets

Currently, I am achieving a center-position look using left positioning on the label as such:

```
QGroupBox::title {
    subcontrol-origin: margin;
    left: 24px;
    padding: 0px 2px;
}
```

Which achieves this look:

[image]

The issue here is that this is not responsive if the boxes were to expand, nor does it work when the label is longer such as with the boxes labeled 10-11.

What is the proper way to responsively center these labels? Is there another way I can accomplish this using normal box layouts?

Thanks

Comment: See also: [QGroupBox.setAlignment](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgroupbox.html#alignment-prop).

Comment: @ekhumoro Perfect, thank you.